# How do I turn off etckeeper. It's preventing me from upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, etckeeper

I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu Karmic to Lucid, but it fails because etckeeper detects changes which happen during `sudo do-release-upgrade` and prevents the running of apt. How do I temporarily turn it off?

Edit:

```
** etckeeper detected uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
** Aborting apt run. Manually commit and restart.

Exception during pm.DoInstall():  E:Problem executing scripts DPkg::Pre-Invoke 'if [ -x /usr/sbin/etckeeper ]; then etckeeper pre-install; fi', E:Sub-process returned an error code

Could not install the upgrades
```

As I said, it's claiming there's changes, even though I just committed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hook should be in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/05etckeeper`. Moving it away should let you disable it.

However, it does not seem that it should prevent upgrades. What sort of error do you get?

Comment: I've used etckeeper during Ubuntu upgrades without any issues - only if it's failing during the APT hooks is it likely to cause problems.  Question is poor quality as it doesn't specify the exact error message.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is with `AVOID_COMMIT_BEFORE_INSTALL` in `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf`. If set to 1 then `do-release-upgrade` will fail. I re-commented that line and all was fine.